# stored procedure not showing while updating model from database in edmx

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, edmx

Created a stored procedure using **SQL Server Management Studio 2014**.Its created successfully.

Now, In my project when I try to update my edmx (right click -> update model from the database) stored procedure is not showing up in the Add tab under stored procedures so that I will check it and update my model.

P.S Checked Connection with DB and it is good.
Previously stored procedures are working fine.

Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Comment: If that doesn't work then open the Model Explorer window, find the stored procedure import, right-click and delete, then update from database again, open the Add > section, go to to stored procs, find the one you just deleted, and check it to import it again. When you rebuild everything should be updated with the new parameters.

Comment: @VishalSuthar Thanks for response.I've tried it but Stored procedure is not showing up in Model Explorer Window because I have created a new one and trying to add it for the first time and not updating previous one currently.

Comment: you need to delete the edmx file and create as new one.\

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by granting execute permission to whatever user/role is in the connection string.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [your_stored_procedure] TO <...>
```